# Buffer of unknown size in Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

So I have to do an exercise like this: `From STDIN take a string of text of any size, and then change every lowercase character to uppercase and vice versa and print it to a file or STDOUT`. The second part is pretty easy. But now how can I take a word, or phrase which is of any length? For example, when I did it previosly I always had a buffer of length like 500 or so, but now it has to take input of any length. How can I do that?

I have to do this in `AT&T` syntax for 32 bit Linux machine.

This is the code I have now: (without changing to upper/lowercase)

```
SYSCALL32 = 0x80
READ = 3
WRITE = 4
STDIN = 0
STDOUT = 1
EXIT = 1
BUF_SIZE = 10


.data
    TEXT_SIZE: .long 0
    BUFOR: .space BUF_SIZE
    BUFOR1: .space BUF_SIZE

.globl _start
.text

_start:
reading:
    movl $READ, %eax
    movl $STDIN, %ebx
    movl $BUFOR, %ecx
    movl $BUF_SIZE, %edx
    int $SYSCALL32
    movl %eax, TEXT_SIZE


    movl $WRITE, %eax
    movl $STDOUT, %ebx
    movl $BUFOR, %ecx
    movl TEXT_SIZE, %edx
    int $SYSCALL32
    jmp reading
```

So here I've read the input to `BUFOR` of length `254`, but what if input was like 260 bytes long?

Comment: You could read the input file in chunks of 500 bytes, observe how you do not need to know the entire input to start working.

Comment: Okay, I read 500 bytes, but what's next, where do I store it or something?

Comment: use a static buffer, and load as often as you need to read the file end. something like `while (!eof()) { num_read=read(500); process(num_read); }`

Comment: Okay, but where do I store the input, and what can I do with it before it gets replaced with the new one?

Comment: read from stdin, write to stdout (it's all written in the exercise). he's not saying you have to store it all, and write it afterwards. read a chunk, process it (and write it), and repeat with the next chunk

Comment: But doesn't writing to the `STDOUT` interrupt reading from the `STDIN`?

Comment: no. they're 2 different, independent file handles

Comment: And how can I for example read 200 bytes, output them, and then start reading from 200th byte, not from the beggining?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137669/discussion-between-tommylee2k-and-frynio).

Comment: @Frynio The operating system keeps a *file pointer* for each open file. It's like a bookmark indicating where your last read ended. When you read from the file descriptor again, it picks off right where you ended last time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple solution for this would be to read in chunks, until the last byte read is a CR (enter is pressed) :

```
SYSCALL32 = 0x80
READ = 3
WRITE = 4
STDIN = 0
STDOUT = 1
EXIT = 1
BUF_SIZE = 10

.data
TEXT_SIZE: .long 0
BUFOR: .space BUF_SIZE
BUFOR1: .space BUF_SIZE

.globl _start
.text

_start:
reading:
    movl $READ, %eax
    movl $STDIN, %ebx
    movl $BUFOR, %ecx
    movl $BUF_SIZE, %edx
    int $SYSCALL32
    movl %eax, TEXT_SIZE

    ; add the code for uppercase <-> lowercase here    

    movl $WRITE, %eax
    movl $STDOUT, %ebx
    movl $BUFOR, %ecx
    movl TEXT_SIZE, %edx
    int $SYSCALL32

    movl $BUFOR, %esi        ; last byte read = $BUFOR + 
    addl TEXT_SIZE, %esi     ; TEXT_SIZE
    mov -1(%esi), %ah        ; -1 
    cmp $0x0a, %ah           ; it if's not CR, keep on reading
    jnz reading

movl $EXIT, %eax             ; otherwise return to OS
int $SYSCALL32
ret
```

Answer (score 0):

The sensible thing would be to read in a fixed-size buffer, process the data and write it out; keep on going as long as `read` returns nonzero. This won't actually limit the input string length in any way, because the system provides some buffer and blocks the write of the process generating your input until your process reads it.

That would be something like this in C:

```
unsigned char buf[512];
int readsz = 0;
while(readsz = read(0, buf, sizeof(buf))) {
    /* ... invert case ... */
    write(1, buf, readsz);
}
```

If instead your assignment does require for some inexplicable reason to *first* read completely in memory the whole string, you'll have to dynamically allocate memory using `malloc` from libc, and continue `realloc`-ing at each iteration of the loop if your buffer finished (you can also do similar stuff with `sbrk`, but it's more complicated). That would be something like:

```
int capacity = 512;
int size = 0;
int readsz = 0;
char *buf = malloc(capacity);
if(buf==0) abort(); /* not enough memory */
while(readsz = read(0, buf+size, capacity-size)) {
    size+=readsz;
    if(size==capacity) {
        capacity *= 2;
        char *nbuf = realloc(buf, capacity);
        if(nbuf==0) abort(); /* not enough memory */
        buf = nbuf;
    }
}
/* now the valid data in buffer is size; do your thing and write it out */
/* ... invert case ... */
write(1, buf, size);
```

But again, this is the most stupid way ever to approach the problem. Use a fixed size buffer.

---

> So here I've read the input to `BUFOR` of length 254, but what if input was like 260 bytes long?

`read` would return you the first 254 bytes, and leave the remaining ones in the stdin buffer; it'll provide them at your next `read` call. You have to loop as long as `read` returns anything different than 0. When you get 0, it means that the standard input was closed on the other side, and you can stop reading and quit.

Comment: I cannot use C libs, so `malloc` cant be used

Comment: @Frynio: you can use the `brk` syscall, but it's more complicated and it's stupid anyway; use the fixed size buffer alternating read and write.

Comment: I've updated the code in question, I guess I am actually doing this, but for now it can even read 30 bytes into 10 byte buffer

Comment: I know, but how can I compare BUF_SIZE with TEXT_SIZE?

Comment: Why should you compare them? Once you called `read` you just care about `TEXT_SIZE`... Read the C example.